# What mistake am i doing here?

Tags: html

```html
    <div class="right">
      <div class="content">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <form id="form-login" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
          <div class="creds">
            <label for="username-login" class="form-label">Username</label>
            <input id="username-login" type="text" name="username">
          </div>
          <div class="creds">
            <label for="password-login" class="form-label">Password</label>
            <input id="password-login" type="password" name="password">
            <span>
              <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true" id="eye"></i>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-element form-submit">
            <button id="logIn" class="login" type="submit" name="login">Log In</button>
            <button id="goRight" class="login off" name="signup">Sign Up</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I am not getting the eye icon class here . Its not showing up in the code.The eye thing is not showing up in the index page when i try to open it. Evrything else is just fine.

Comment: What do you mean "not Showing" in your code ?

Comment: Impossible to tell from the code you show. Are you including font awesome?

Comment: You need to link the CDN in your head tag. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-YWzhKL2whUzgiheMoBFwW8CKV4qpHQAEuvilg9FAn5VJUDwKZZxkJNuGM4XkWuk94WCrrwslk8yWNGmY1EduTA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />`

Comment: RïshïKêsh Kümar, editing the question to fix the problem is not now Stack Overflow works. Edit has been rolled back.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add Font Awesome for the icon to appear

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="creds">
  <label for="password-login" class="form-label">Password</label>
  <input id="password-login" type="password" name="password">
  <span>
    <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true" id="eye"></i>
  </span>
</div>
```